# Trouble running gensim Word2Vec

Tags: word2vec, gensim

I am trying to train word embeddings(word2vec) on my own dataset using gensim library.

`model = Word2Vec(sentences=alp[:20],size=100, window=6, min_count=5)`

where alp is a list of list containing tokens of individual sentences in my corpus.

I get the following error whenever I try to train the w2v model.Please help.

```
`Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 867, in worker_loop
    tally, raw_tally = self._do_train_job(sentences, alpha, (work, neu1))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 785, in _do_train_job
    tally += train_batch_cbow(self, sentences, alpha, work, neu1, 
self.compute_loss)
  File "gensim/models/word2vec_inner.pyx", line 458, in gensim.models.word2vec_inner.train_batch_cbow (./gensim/models/word2vec_inner.c:5642)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

`Exception in thread Thread-1:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 867, in worker_loop
        tally, raw_tally = self._do_train_job(sentences, alpha, (work, neu1))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 785, in _do_train_job
        tally += train_batch_cbow(self, sentences, alpha, work, neu1, self.compute_loss)
      File "gensim/models/word2vec_inner.pyx", line 458, in gensim.models.word2vec_inner.train_batch_cbow (./gensim/models/word2vec_inner.c:5642)
    ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`
```

`

Answer (score 3):

The problem was solved by type casting alp into list of lists.

Comment: For any future visitors, I encountered a similar error when passing in a numpy sparse matrix (instead of a gensim corpus).

Comment: I too encountered the same issue. I converted my list of lists to numpy array for some preprocessing. Converted it back to lists and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The above code works perfectly for me. Can you verify the type of `alp[:20]`.
Working code (tested in `gensim version 3.4.0`):

```
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec  
model = Word2Vec(sentences=alp[0:20],size=100,window=6,min_count=5)
```

`alp` looks like follow:

```
    alp = [['this','is','first','sentence'],
          ['this','is','second','sentence'],
          [..],  
          [..],  
          [..]]
```

Comment: alp is a list of list. `alp[0] = ['i', 'think', 'we', 'could', 'import', 'the', 'old', 'comment', 'via', 'rsync', '', 'but', 'from', 'there', 'we', 'need', 'to', 'go', 'via', 'email', '', 'i', 'think', 'it', 'be', 'easier', 'than', 'cach', 'the', 'status', 'on', 'each', 'bug', 'and', 'than', 'import', 'bite', 'here', 'and', 'there', '__eou__', '__eot__', 'it', 'would', 'be', 'veri', 'easi', 'to', 'keep', 'a', 'hash', 'db', 'of', 'messageid', '__eou__', 'sound', 'good', '__eou__', '__eot__', 'ok', '__eou__', 'perhap', 'we', 'can',.... 'apt_preferec', '__eou__'...] ` same with alp[1] and so on.